# Type mismatch in parameterized class - but why?

Tags: scala, types

Assume, we have the following definitions:

```
abstract class A
class B extends A

trait Test[T <: A] {
  def foo(t: T) = println("I'm Foo")

  def bar(t: T) = t match {
    case b: B => foo(b)
    case _ => println("Bar says: Other")
  }
}
```

The Scala compiler will complain with an error:

```
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : b.type (with underlying type B)
 required: T
           case b: B => foo(b)
                            ^
```

I do not understand, what is wrong here, since variable `b` is the same object as `t` and `t` is type `T` ?

Or maybe, the compiler does consider variable `b` as a new one (without the relationship to `t`). Then, `b` is a subtype of `A`, but not necessary a subtype of `T`, since `T` can be any arbitrary subtype of `A`. Is this the correct explanation ?

Answer (score 3):

`case b: B` actually will produce code like:

```
if(t.isInstanceOf[B]) {
  val b = t.asInstanceOf[B]
  // ...
}
```

so `b` is not `t`. It still refers to the same instance, but the type of `b` is `B` and not `T`. Same thing here:

```
def foo(x: String) = println(x)

foo("Foo bar".asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyRef
 required: String
                  foo("Foo bar".asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it right to say, that with the cast `asInstanceOf` cast (which is also included in the `match-case`) delets all other type information and the compiler only sees the new casted type ?

Comment: But `trait C; def foo(c: C) = println("I'm Foo")` and `def bar(c: C) = c match { case b: B => foo(b) }` is just fine. The problem is that abstract types and pattern matching interact in confusing ways.

Comment: @Travis, this will only work, if `B extends C`.
@John Yes, when you cast on object to a type, the compiler will handle it as an object of this type.

Comment: But that's just not the case. Start a new REPL and stick `trait B` on the front of the commands in my previous comment and you won't get the compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

You said to the compiler you require `T` to be a subtype of `A` for all possible values of `T` but give a very specific subtype of `A`, namely `B` to `foo`.
If you had a `Test[C]` with `class C extends B`, `foo` would expect to get a `C` but get a `B` so the types wouldn't match.

Unfortunately even if you don't introduce a new class and seal the hierarchy, the compiler doesn't seem to care for that or may have other legitimate complaints that I don't know of.

Comment: Thank you to make this clear. I was thinking in a similar direction.

Comment: Don't thank me yet. I don't know if that is really the compilers reasoning, I just think it is :)  
It is still safe in this case since `bar` accepts only the same types as `foo`.